# Quickly Network commands in python

Tags: networking, application-development, python, quickly, shared-folders

I am working on a program that mounts a windows shared network drive using quickly. So I sat up my GUI and everything.. But I don't know any python commands that mount a network place.. Usually when I use the Linux script I use this command

gvfs-mount smb://192.168.2.25/"Extended (D)"

but of course this won't work with python.. So can anyone help me or give me the command to try to mount a specific network place?

Comment: why not just `import os; os.system("gvfs-mount smb://192.168.2.25/\"Extended (D)\"");`?

Comment: @Ysangkok thank you so much!! It worked.. Now I only need to finalize it and I will be done

Comment: No no no no! Not again with the `os.system` "solutions"! We have `GIO` for a reason: http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [`GIO`](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) which will do the trick. Especially the [`GMountOperation`](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMountOperation.html) and [`GVolume`](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GVolume.html).

There's a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051628/1153996) on SO which handles your issue.

Comment: Yeah I will try various commands and functions to make it mountable .. Although I am thinking of expanding it to accept a user Input for example 192.168.0.1/C and when the user hit the mount button.. It will mount the drive.. Any idea if I can do this?

Comment: Just use a `Gtk.Entry` and its `get_text()` method to get the user input.